# Number Theory , modular arithmetic

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

I need to solve the equation $a^2+b^2=9ab-13$ in primes for $a,b>2$. I need some help. Is this problem need advanced number theory?

Answer (score 2):

There are solutions for primes $a,b$. Solving the quadratic equation 
$a^2+b^2-9ab+13=0$ we obtain that $77a^2-52$ and $77b^2-52$ must be a square. So we have that $a$ and $b$ are (different) prime numbers satisfying equations
$77a^2-52=x^2$ and $77b^2-52=y^2$ of Pell type.
However, this gives solutions in primes, e.g.,
$$
(a,b)=(17,151)
$$
satisfies $a^2+b^2-9ab+13=0$. Another solution is $(a,b)=(2,17)$, but here $p=2$.

So Pell's equation
$$
77x^2-52=y^2
$$
has integral solutions with $x$ prime, e.g., $(x,y)=(151,1325)$.

Comment: You have +13 not -13

Comment: exactly @arberavdullahu  he made mistake

Comment: I corrected the mistake.

Comment: How statement is not true? If solution exists prove if not again prove. But you have to solve in primes however 1325 is not prime @DietrichBurde

Comment: No, you said $a$ and $b$ should be primes, which is the case for $a=17$ and $b=151$. I edited my statement. By the way, you never accepted any answer so far, to all of your $10$ questions, right?

Comment: ok I need to solve in primes. I need complete solution. In the statement I wanted to say my approach is not useful. I need help. But what you say?

Comment: You can get all solutions by solving Pell's equation $77x^2-52=y^2$, where $x$ needs to be prime (but not $y$ necessarily).

Comment: ok, look subst. $u=2a-9b$ then equation turns $u^2-77b^2=-52$ right? Here $b$ is prime but $u$ need not be prime right? I don't solve $(u,b)$ I  need prime solutions $(a,b)$. Pell equation has infinitely many solutions maybe but your answer is not clear to my problem

Comment: @DietrichBurde in my statement I want to say I found solution but I want to prove there is no others. for this I used mod arithm. but it is not useful. How can I solve that equation in primes

Comment: Dietrich, note the pairs are consecutive elements of a sequence $x_{n+2} = 9 x_{n+1} - x_n.$ One of the two sequences begins $1,7, 62, 551, 4897...$ while the other has your example $1,2, 17, 151, 1342,...$ In both sequences primes become rare.

Comment: Prime 2
 Prime 17
 Prime 151
 Prime 11927
 Prime 8372737
 Prime 5877649447
 Prime 703430290475264962318075607

Comment: Prime 1
 Prime 7
 Prime 834855389669557847
 Prime 46291896486731038104001
 Prime 5540160651964807748265850949780964096401
 Prime 3285361824670481756257291355464741249289745923245964305130237987178751514167516517042876610366285751

Comment: @WillJagy Very good! In the original question the OP said there were no solutions with primes $p,q>2$. After my answer it was edited to find all prime solutions . My answer was meant for the first version of the question.

Comment: Dietrich, right, I do not think there is any hope of proving your $17, 151$ is the only time both numbers are prime. The original task of finding a single prime pair is reasonable for a contest or contest preparation problem, as it is precisely the method they now cal Vieta Jumping, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping